# Bundle install runs from incorrect directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, thor

I'm building a simple `thor` based generator for some internal projects, and can't seem to get `bundle install` running from the correct directory.

As I run the new [APP_NAME] function, it *should* create the directories and files, then run `bundle install` to install the gems required for the application.

The source of the generator function:

```
def create
  puts "Creating application #{name}"

  directory 'application', "#{name}"

  Dir.chdir("#{Dir.pwd}/#{name}") do
    puts `bundle install`
  end
end
```

And the console output from running the command that calls this create method:

```
$ bundle exec bin/my_gem new test_app
Creating application test_app
      create  test_app
      create  test_app/Gemfile
      create  test_app/Guardfile
      create  test_app/README.md
      create  test_app/app/controllers
      create  test_app/app/helpers
      create  test_app/app/models
      create  test_app/app/views
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using my_gem (0.0.1) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

As you can see, it is running `bundle install` but it's running it in my current directory (`thor`, `bundler`, `my_gem`), as opposed to the `test_app` directory (`guard`, `guard-coffeescript`, `guard-less`, and others) .

Running other commands such as `ls` or `pwd` give the expected results:

```
Gemfile
Guardfile
README.md
app
```

and

```
/Users/davidlumley/Development/Gems/my_gem/test_app
```

Not sure if it makes any difference, but I use RVM for managing my rubies.

Comment: "Not sure if it makes any difference, but I use RVM for managing my rubies." - Yes :)

Comment: Yes of course it manging ruby but with the help of rvm you should  create gemset and use that gemset directory for installing gem and there will be no issues which you faced now..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds like your app is already using bundler and you have a bundler-inside-bundler problem. Try this:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  puts `bundle install`
end
```

I'm guessing what's happening is that your outer bundler sets the `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` env variable to your app's Gemfile, and then your inner bundler ends up inheriting it.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this i will sure helps you.

```
      rvm gemset create app_name


      rvm use ruby-1.9.2@app_name
```

Ruby version what else you used.

then install bundler gem

```
      gem install bundler.
```

Then bundle install and run server..

Comment: I'm using a fresh gemset at the moment, it has `thor` and `bundler` installed. The issue isn't that the bundle isn't getting installed, it's that my generator isn't running the command in the appropriate directory, and therefore it's using the _wrong_ Gemfile.

Comment: Oh i have faced this problem then i use this trick.go to directory of app through command line and install all gem one by one and also sure after any gem either it is installed in the right gemset directory.

Comment: I'm trying to automate that, which is why I'm trying to run `bundle install` programmatically, similar to the way rails does in its generators.